# How can I repair a PowerPoint file (or other Office file) on Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2008

I have a few .ppt files that I cannot open on my iMac running Mac OS X 10.6, with Office 2008 for Mac:

[image]

Does anyone have any solutions, preferably free?

Note that I get the same issue with NeoOffice and OpenOffice.

Comment: The ":" in the name looks kind of suspicious, but I'm no expert at this. Try renaming :D

Comment: The ":" is just between the name of the Volume it's on, and the name of the file. Nothing weird.

Comment: Have you tried opening the files in Google Docs? That might be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "trolle3000" suggested, I tried with Google Docs. It didn't really showed the document correctly, but I've been able to retrieve the picture from inside, somehow!

So Google Documents was my solution, thank to Trolle3000!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

download [neoffice](http://www.neooffice.org/) or [openoffice](http://porting.openoffice.org/mac/) and see if if they can open it.

Comment: No, I already tried with Neo, doesn't work either.

Comment: maybe you should update your post with the things you've tried...

Comment: None of them works.